# rich:calendar value does not change in bean

Tags: jsf

I have the following xhtml snippet where there are two `rich:calendar` (simply, date range for search):-

```
    <h:panelGroup>
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['lblstrtdteh']}" />
            <h:outputText value="   *" escape="false" styleClass="reqField" />
        </h:panelGroup>
        <rich:calendar id="startDateFldVhrs" datePattern="dd-MM-yyyy" locale="#{sessionBean.locale}"
            value="#{productsBean.startDate}" />

        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['lblenddteh']}" />
            <h:outputText value="   *" escape="false" styleClass="reqField" />
        </h:panelGroup>
        <rich:calendar id="endDateFldVhrs" datePattern="dd-MM-yyyy"
            value="#{productsBean.endDate}" />
```

Here's my bean's accessors:-

```
    /**
 * 
 * @return
 */
public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param startDate
 */
public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
    System.out.println("setting startDate: " + startDate);
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 */
public Date getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param endDate
 */
public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
    System.out.println("setting endDate: " + endDate);
}
```

When I select a different date than displayed, I don't see the print of setter methods, neither does it takes the displayed value when search button is fired (both dates are executed in the search commandButton).
Something I am missing?

The fields are initialized with `new Date()` and it stays that way forever it seems.

Answer (score 0):

In JSF your set methods is only called when you call an action, for example when you render or process a field, when you POST data to server, when some AJAX is called.

If you want your rich:calendar call your set method you show execute some AJAX and update your field.

Richfaces <= 3.X

```
 <a4j:form>
      <rich:calendar value="#{bean.date}" id="myCalendar">
          <a4j:support event="onchanged" reRender="myCalendar" ajaxSingle="true"/>
      </rich:calendar>
 </a4j:form>
```

Richfaces 4.X +

```
<rich:calendar id="myCalendar">
    <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="myCalendar" />
</rich:calendar>
```